# Apache2 + mod_proxy = server dying periodically

Tags: nginx, apache-2.2, mod-proxy

I'm running apache2 with mod_proxy to forward certain requests to an nginx server running on the same machine. Occasioanaly the Apache server will stop responding all together until a restart. Checking the httpd.log shows the following lines happening every second or 2:

The timeout specified has expired: proxy: error reading status line from remote server localhost
proxy: Error reading from remote server returned by /

I've searched google for an answer but found nothing definitive other than people mentioning mod_proxy as the cause.

Does anyone have a clue where to look next or even how to solve it?

Thanks,
J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have KeepAlive enabled in your ProxyPass directive? I've seen this before, and in nearly every case, KeepAlive was the culprit.

Comment: I did have KeepAlive set so it was more than likely the culprit. I decided to remove Apache from the equation all together and open up the nginx port so stop it happening again. Thanks

Comment: Actually, you would actually want to have KeepAlive enabled -- you just need to ensure that the timeouts in Apache and Nginx match.